# how to fix my code to give the calculated cash amount plus interest rate as a final result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't get my code to work. I keek getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to function.__format
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```py
def formatCurrency(money):
    moneyString = f'${money:.2f}'
    return moneyString
    
    def updateBalance(amount, interest):
    amount = (1+(interest*1))
    return updateBalance



    ### Main Program ###
    savBal = float(input("Enter your savings balance: "))
    chBal = float(input("Enter your checking balance: "))
    savIR = float(input("Enter your saving interest rate %: "))
    chIR = float(input("Enter your checking interest rate %: "))

    savBal = updateBalance(savBal, savIR)
    chBal = updateBalance(chBal, chIR)

    print("Your updated savings balance is" , formatCurrency(savBal))
    print("Your updated checking balance is" , formatCurrency(chBal))
```

Comment: Your function `updateBalance` returns a reference to itself, not the `amount`.

Comment: i re-wrote my code and now its not giving the right calculations. i changed the defining function to:    def updateBalance(amount, interest):
    amount = amount+(interest/100)*365)
    return amount

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure you always post full details of errors you run into, such as the line number where the error occurred, and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a typo error at  `def updateBalance(amount, interest): amount = (1+(interest*1)) return updateBalance #here's the problem`

what you want is:  `def updateBalance(amount, interest): amount = (1+(interest*1)) return amount`

Answer (score 1):

The code is not working with the below error because, in function `formatCurrency`, the variable value should be of type `float`, but you are passing a function reference as a return value from `updateBalance` Function

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to function.**format**

Replace the function return value with the `amount` variable and your code will work and solve the issue.

```
def updateBalance(amount, interest):
    amount = (1+(interest*1))
    return amount
```